# Video crashes Unity game on Daydream

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, video, daydream

I'm trying to play a video on **Daydream** in my **Unity** game. However, the video causes the game to segfault whenever I try to play it. To verify that the video is what is causing the crash to occur, I removed the scene containing the video from my game. Sure enough, everything was working fine once that scene was gone. I am not sure what *exactly* is causing the crash, though.

I managed to capture `logcat` output from a running instance of the game via `adb logcat -s Unity ActivityManager PackageManager dalvikvm DEBUG` and the parts that seem relevant to the crash are seen below (I do not wish to post a full dump of the logs since some of the information is private):

```
...
08-14 07:58:00.197 16524 16617 E Unity   : Unable to find AudioPluginOculusSpatializer
08-14 07:58:00.197 16524 16617 D Unity   : Unable to lookup library path for 'libaudioplugingvrunity', native render plugin support disabled.
08-14 07:58:00.197 16524 16617 E Unity   : Unable to find libaudioplugingvrunity
08-14 07:58:00.207 16524 16617 D Unity   : Unable to lookup library path for 'libAudioPluginOculusSpatializer', native render plugin support disabled.
08-14 07:58:00.207 16524 16617 E Unity   : Unable to find libAudioPluginOculusSpatializer
...
08-14 07:58:19.257 16842 16842 F DEBUG   : *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
08-14 07:58:19.257 16842 16842 F DEBUG   : Build fingerprint: 'ZTE/P996A01_N/ailsa_ii:7.1.1/NMF26F/20170301.161705:user/release-keys'
08-14 07:58:19.257 16842 16842 F DEBUG   : Revision: '0'
08-14 07:58:19.257 16842 16842 F DEBUG   : ABI: 'arm'
08-14 07:58:19.257 16842 16842 F DEBUG   : pid: 16524, tid: 16671, name: GLThread 513  >>> com.REDACTED.REDACTED <<<
08-14 07:58:19.257 16842 16842 F DEBUG   : signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x20
08-14 07:58:19.257 16842 16842 F DEBUG   :     r0 00000000  r1 00000000  r2 fffe1a66  r3 72e77f00
08-14 07:58:19.257 16842 16842 F DEBUG   :     r4 f00f2008  r5 cf5fc900  r6 00000000  r7 cc6fc7e4
08-14 07:58:19.257 16842 16842 F DEBUG   :     r8 cc6fc828  r9 cc6fc738  sl cf5fc928  fp ce43fa10
08-14 07:58:19.257 16842 16842 F DEBUG   :     ip cc6fc7e4  sp cc6fc610  lr cd2ae69b  pc cd329f58  cpsr 600d0030
08-14 07:58:19.257 16842 16842 F DEBUG   : 
08-14 07:58:19.257 16842 16842 F DEBUG   : backtrace:
08-14 07:58:19.257 16842 16842 F DEBUG   :     #00 pc 0026ff58  /data/app/com.google.vr.vrcore-2/lib/arm/libvrcore_native.so
08-14 07:58:19.257 16842 16842 F DEBUG   :     #01 pc 001f4697  /data/app/com.google.vr.vrcore-2/lib/arm/libvrcore_native.so
08-14 07:58:19.257 16842 16842 F DEBUG   :     #02 pc 001f4821  /data/app/com.google.vr.vrcore-2/lib/arm/libvrcore_native.so
08-14 07:58:19.257 16842 16842 F DEBUG   :     #03 pc 001f5613  /data/app/com.google.vr.vrcore-2/lib/arm/libvrcore_native.so
08-14 07:58:19.257 16842 16842 F DEBUG   :     #04 pc 001dd7f1  /data/app/com.google.vr.vrcore-2/lib/arm/libvrcore_native.so
08-14 07:58:19.257 16842 16842 F DEBUG   :     #05 pc 0001df9d  /data/app/com.REDACTED.REDACTED-2/lib/arm/libgvr.so (gvr_render_reprojection_thread+24)
08-14 07:58:19.257 16842 16842 F DEBUG   :     #06 pc 000a631f  /data/app/com.REDACTED.REDACTED-2/lib/arm/libgvr.so (Java_com_google_vr_ndk_base_GvrApi_nativeRenderReprojectionThread+14)
08-14 07:58:19.257 16842 16842 F DEBUG   :     #07 pc 000b73f1  /data/app/com.REDACTED.REDACTED-2/oat/arm/base.odex (offset 0xab000)
08-14 07:58:20.787  1321 16843 W ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.REDACTED.REDACTED/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity
08-14 07:58:20.797  1321 16843 D ActivityManager: --zc to bg, ProcessRecord{fef975a 16524:com.REDACTED.REDACTED/u0a139} rx/tx = 115341 624574
08-14 07:58:20.807  1321  1386 W ActivityManager: Failed setting process group of 16524 to 1
08-14 07:58:20.877  1321  2828 I ActivityManager: Process com.REDACTED.REDACTED (pid 16524) has died is serviceb: false
...
```

I have not made modifications to how my video is played on **Daydream** versus how it is played on desktop, except that I changed the "**Importer Version**" to VideoClip instead of MovieTexture (which is not supported on Android). What am I missing that could cause a video to crash my game on Daydream?

Comment: Will the video play in an Android build (e.g. non VR mode)?

Comment: @birdimus Yes, I forgot to mention that.